# Как поставить placeholder в UIImageView пока нет картинки?

Tags: ios, swift

Вот собственно как сейчас выглядит мой `UIImageView`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а вот как я хочу сделать

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как поставить этот `placeholder` - `no photo selected` в `UIImageView` пока там нет картинки?

Comment: Не пишу под яблоки, но думаю нужны два `ImageView` друг на дружке, пока нет второго, виден нижний, как только он появляется, нижний за ним не видно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если Вы хотите просто добавить текст, то можно его врисовать или просто добавить label. Второй вариант очень простой, в виде extension:

```
extension UIImageView {
    func addText(_ text: String) {
        let lblText = UILabel(frame: self.bounds)
        lblText.text = text
        lblText.textAlignment = .center
        self.addSubview(lblText)
    }

    func removeAll() {
        for v in self.subviews { //удаляет все, если что-то другое добавили, проверять что v это UILabel
            v.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
}
```

Когда необходимо добавить:

```
ivTest.addText("No Photo Selected")
```

удалить:

```
ivTest.removeAll()
```

Ну и бонусы в виде легко задать какой нам необходимо шрифт/размер шрифта и т.п.

---

Не extension:

```
func addText(_ text: String, to imageView: UIImageView) {
    let lblText = UILabel(frame: imageView.bounds)
    lblText.text = text
    lblText.textAlignment = .center
    imageView.addSubview(lblText)
}

func removeText(from imageView: UIImageView) {
    for v in imageView.subviews {
        v.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

Использование:

```
addText("No Photo Selected", to: ivTest)
removeText(from: ivTest)
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй импортировать дефолтное изображение в файлы проекта и при инициализации UIImageView подсовывать его. А при получении изображения, которое должно быть, просто через код с главного потока меняй на требуемое.

Answer (score 0):

У `imageView` есть свойство `image`, вот пока вашего изображения нет, поставьте туда любую картинку `imageView.image = "temp_image"`. Когда получите свою картинку замените. Поставить временную картинку можно в IB